# Cannot capture output of block in Rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I've run into a problem with a custom Rails FormBuilder, which drives me crazy since yesterday evening. Basically I want to have an optional block to one of my builder methods, so that I can show additional content within my main `content_tag`:

```
def form_field(method, &block)
  content_tag(:div, class: 'field') do
    concat label(method, "Label #{method}")
    concat text_field(method)
    capture(&block) if block_given?
  end
end
```

When I call that method in one of my Slim templates, like so:

```
= f.form_field :email do
  small.help-text
    | Your email will never be public.
```

it inserts the block (here: the help text within `<small>`) above the actual output of the `content_tag`:

```
<small class="help-text">Your email will never be public.</small>
<div class="field">
    <label for="user_email">Label email</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
</div>
```

I tried several other variants, but it seems that I can never capture the output of the `block`. Any ideas - and maybe even more interesting: explanations on this behaviour? I read several articles about that topic and also had a look at the Rails source, but couldn't really figure out why it's behaving like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Kitto says, `:capture`, `:concat` and many more others helpers are implemented to @template.

In my customs `FormBuilder`, i have this :

```
module CustomFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  delegate :content_tag, :concat, to: :@template

  [ ... your code ... ]
end
```

Comment: This should be in some sort of best practices guide. Major thumbs up to you and @Kitto!

Answer (score 4):

So, after some more digging-around, it turns out that the problem lies in the FormBuilder and how itself deals with output buffers. Looking into the source code for [ActionView FormHelpers](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/477fae3eb3d3b3bfdbe28586fecb8578c0be4721/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1924), gives a hint to call capture on @template, like so:

```
def form_field(method, &block)
  content = @template.capture(&block) if block_given?
  content_tag(:div, class: 'field') do
    concat label(method, "Label #{method}")
    concat text_field(method)
    concat content if content.present?
  end
end
```